# How to pass a object array's value to a method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, quicksort

I have a quick and simple question that I have somehow not been able to find an answer for.

I have a method called quick_srt_int that is able to sort an integer array, my issue however is that my array is formed from an object and I want to be able to sort the array from a specific sub value (please correct me on how this is called).

Just to give you some background this is how the array is declared.

```
student[index] = new Person(name, id, age, gpa);
```

I need to be able to sort it for id, age, and gpa at different times but don't know how to pass the value. my guess is that i would have to pass it like so:

```
public void ageSort() {
    quick_srt_int(student[].age, 0, student[].age.length - 1);
}
```

Please show me how to do this properly.

I also need to modify the quick sort method to support double type values because gpa is in double form and I cannot cast it for sorting.

Any help is MUCH appreciated, thank you so much.

The quick sort method looks like so:

```
public static void quick_srt_int(int array[], int low, int n) {
    int lo = low;
    int hi = n;
    if (lo >= n) {
        return;
    }
    int mid = array[(lo + hi) / 2];
    while (lo < hi) {
        while (lo < hi && array[lo] < mid) {
            lo++;
        }
        while (lo < hi && array[hi] > mid) {
            hi--;
        }
        if (lo < hi) {
            int T = array[lo];
            array[lo] = array[hi];
            array[hi] = T;
        }
    }
    if (hi < lo) {
        int T = hi;
        hi = lo;
        lo = T;
    }
    quick_srt_int(array, low, lo);
    quick_srt_int(array, lo == low ? lo + 1 : lo, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Logan said, you must use a Comparator or your Person class must implement the Comparable interface. I'll give you an example:

```
public class Person implements Comparable {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int age;
    private int gpa;

    public Person(String name, int id, int age, int gpa) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    //getters and setters here...

    //logic for the comparison
    //NOTE: you can improve the comparison algorithm.
    public int compareTo (Person p) {
        //0 means both Person objects are equal.
        // > 0 means **this** object is greater than p object.
        // < 0 means **this** object is less than p object.
        int result = 0;
        //comparison by id
        if (this.id > p.id) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            if (this.id < p.id) {
                result = -1;
            } else { //same id, check by age
                if (this.age > p.age) {
                    result = 1;
                } else {
                    if (this.age < p.age) {
                        result = -1;
                    } else { //same id and age, check by gpa
                        if (this.gpa > p.gpa) {
                            result = 1;
                        } else {
                            if (this.gpa < p.gpa) {
                                result = -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And now, send the Person array to your quicksort method:

```
public void ageSort() {
    quick_srt_int(student[], 0, student[].age.length - 1);
}

public static void quick_srt_int(Person array[], int low, int n) {
    //your logic...
}
```

If you want to specify the comparison function for this, you need to add a parameter to your `quick_srt_int` function to set a class which implements the Comparator interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `Comparator`.  There's an example very similar to your problem [here](http://You%27re%20looking%20for%20a%20%60Comparator%60.%20%20There%27s%20an%20example%20very%20similar%20to%20your%20%5Bhere%5Dhttp://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your person class needs to implement comparable or comparator. [example sort by id](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)